# pass className as props failed in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this in parent component

```
<StatusDropdown className="pull-right" />
```

Then I have a functional component like this

```
import classNames from 'classnames'

    const StatusDropdown = (props) => (
        <div className={classNames('dropdown', {props.className})}></div>
    )

    export default StatusDropdown;
```

But I got unexpected token in `props.className`, can't I pass className as props?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name to forwardClassName on our parent component and it will work. className is used by component internally.

```
<StatusDropdown forwardClassName="pull-right" />

import classNames from 'classnames'

const StatusDropdown = (props) => (
    <div className={classNames('dropdown', props.forwardClassName)}></div>
)

export default StatusDropdown;
```

Comment: remove then {} around props.forwardClassName

Comment: worked but I got warning of ` Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?`

Comment: then you have in your code or a lib something like this `<div class="" />`  and need to change it.